# Angular valuechanges call multiple times while Page loading

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4 and i am checking is any value is changed by user or not? In my page there are more than 100 control(textbox ,dropdown and editable grid)

I need to check only if any value is changed or not. For that i am using below code but it is called multiple times while pageload.

How i can avoid this.i need **valuechange** will execute only on when user change any value.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, HostListener, OnChanges, DoCheck, AfterViewChecked,OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";


 @ViewChild('fromNote') fnotes;
 
 ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.fnotes.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
            alert('changed');
        });
}
```

Comment: Do `.next()` on `valueChanges` of `fnotes`, only when the user changes the value. So the `subscribe` method gets the value when the use changes the value.

Comment: Would you provide HTML code where you have use `#fromNote`?

Answer (score 3):

**`In Angular 5`**  you’ll be able to specify the `update mode` for 
**`forms and form controls`**.

**`updateOn: 'submit'`** runs the value changes only when the form is **`submitted`**.

```
this.nameForm = new FormGroup ({
  firstname: new FormControl('', {
    validators: Validators.required,
    updateOn: 'submit'
  }),
  lastname: new FormControl('', {
    validators: Validators.required,
    updateOn: 'submit'
  })
});
```

Different options are `updateOn: 'blur'` and `updateOn: 'submit'`

`const c = new FormControl('', { updateOn: 'blur' });` and

```
 const c = new FormControl('', { updateOn: 'submit' });
```

> From [Official Documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) `updateOn to 'submit'`,  will delay
>   value and validity updates until the parent form of the control fires
>   a submit event.

Comment: @pushp, have you checked this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), `ngOnChanges` gets called by default before the `ngOnInit` as well as on data-bound input properties change.

So, if you want to avoid that, try to:

- Limit the `@Input` bound property changes on page load
- Use a flag to detect only the user-made changes :

for instance:

```
private initialised = false;

ngInInit(){
  ...
  this.initialized = true;
}

ngOnChanges(){
  if(this.initilazied){<your code here>}
}
```

Or: use a different lifecylce hook, or use the `(change)` method calls in the component

Answer (score 0):

```
            import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, HostListener, OnChanges, DoCheck, AfterViewChecked,OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";

            @ViewChild('fromNote') fnotes;
            public subScription;
            ngAfterViewInit() {
                 this.subScription=  this.fnotes.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
                     alert('changed');
                 });
            }

            ngOnDestroy() {
                 this.subScription.unsubscribe()
            }
```

Are you trying to unsubscribe to the valuechanges in ngOnDestroy ? If not try to unsubscribe. Valuechanges is an observable and needs to be unsubscribed or it will look for changes in every instance.